# How can I get logs from all containers via corev1.PodLogOptions?

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am using [kubernetes/client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) to retrieve some pod logs. I am able to retrieve logs should the pod have one container as such

```golang
req := client.CoreV1().Pods("namespace").GetLogs("mypod", &corev1.PodLogOptions{})
logs, err := req.Stream()
[...]
```

This works well, until I encounter a pod that has *more than one container,* to which I get the following error

> a container name must be specified for pod xxx, choose one of: [aaa
>   bbb] or one of the init containers: [aaa bbb]

I was hoping to find an accommodating field on the [`corev1.PodLogOptions`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/core/v1#PodLogOptions) object, but am only finding a specific `Container` field.

I'm searching for an `--all-containers` equivalent as offered with the REST client.

```sh
$ kubectl logs mypod --all-containers
```

Is this possible? Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look in `kubectl` code they just get all relevant containers in a pod and then iterate over them and gather logs container by container. So I don't think there's REST API endpoint that would do that for you.

See here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/19fd05792d8c806a5024d6bbbdd7d66d3234cbcb/pkg/polymorphichelpers/logsforobject.go#L86

Comment: Yep, this is what I ended up doing, simply iterating over `Spec.Containers`. Works for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite specialized and not easy for me to have snippet in head, but the strategy was always the following: if you want to mimic the behaviour of kubectl you obviously should first inspect sources of kubectl. You can start from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/tree/19fd05792d8c806a5024d6bbbdd7d66d3234cbcb/pkg/cmd/logs) looking for the pattern you want, then you have to inspect supplementary packages, tests and etc. having a nice trip. In my experience, some sugar operations in kubectl are possible not because they are supported natively by REST API, but because of iteration cycles with dispatching of many different requests.

Hope it helps!